# Youtube streaming get disable itself

Tags: youtube, live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api

YouTube streaming get automatically disable itself. We are doing live streaming through VMIX software. It works fine but sometimes it automatically stop the streaming on the VMIX software we checked streaming looks good.

We stopped and restart the streaming on VMIX but it didn't make any difference until you go to open YouTube live streaming page and then stop and start the streaming from VMIX.

Can anyone face this type of issue? Please guide if you have any clue on this thanks.

I have tried gone through YouTube documentation but didn't got anything on this.

Comment: I have a similar issue with OBS studio, everytime I want to live stream I am enforced to go on YouTube live streaming webpage to make the live work.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison did you got any solution on this?

Comment: I said all I know, I potentially think about doing a web-scrape like approach to avoid having to manually go on the YouTube live streaming webpage.